# How to bind List<string> to a DependencyProperty

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I'm trying to learn about DependencyProperty. To do so I want to create a new `UserControl` which displays a list.

The location of this list must exist in the parent as a property. For this, I only have `MainWindow`, MainWindowViewModel (these are the parent) and the `UserControl` (the child) (which is currently using code behind).

In my MainWindow I have

```
<Grid>
    <uc:RecentList MessageList="{Binding Messages}" />    
</Grid>
```

And in the code behind

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
}
```

And the ViewModel

```
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    this.Messages = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    this.Messages.Add("Item 1");
    this.Messages.Add("Item 2");
    this.T = "hi";
}

public ObservableCollection<string> Messages { get; set; }
```

In the `UserControl` I have

```
<Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MessageList}"></ListView>
    <TextBlock Text="I'm such text to verify this control is showing" />
</Grid>
```

And the code behind is

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MessageListProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register(
"MessageList", typeof(IEnumerable<string>), typeof(RecentList));

public IEnumerable<string> MessageList
{
    get { return (IEnumerable<string>)GetValue(MessageListProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MessageListProperty, value); }
}
```

The issue I have is the binding is not working. I can see this in the Output Window, with the Error:

> Error 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'MessageList' property not found on 'object' ''MainWindowViewModel' (HashCode=26034861)'. BindingExpression:Path=MessageList; DataItem='MainWindowViewModel' (HashCode=26034861); target element is 'ListView' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

I understand the issue but I am confused by it. It's looking in the right place (in the MainWindowViewModel) but it is looking I don't understand why the `UserControl` is looking for the `MessageList` in the `MainWindowViewModel`. I guess it's because that is where I set the datacontext but, I also thought it that if I added `this.DataContext = this;` to the UserControl's constructor then it's wrong (I've tried it, it didn't work either).

Updating my `UserControl` to

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MessageList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"></ListView>
```

Helps in the sense I don't get the error message, but I also don't see the result.

This is what I think is happening when the application loads:

1. MainWindow loads
2. MainWindow then see's the UserControl and notes it requires a property.
3. Before WPF calls the UserControl constructor, it grabs the value of the property. It then initializes the component and automatically pushes the value to the UserControl's property

How can my UserControl use the Parents (MainWindow) property (Messages)

Comment: This has been done before, e.g. any control that allows you to bind to an [`ItemsSource`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ItemsControl.cs,185).  Notice the use of `IEnumerable`.  I would also take a shot in the dark and say that you don't need a "custom control" and can/should probably avoid it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Binding in the UserControl's XAML should have the UserControl instance as its source object, e.g. like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MessageList,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
```

Alternatively you could set `x:Name` on the UserControl and use an ElementName binding:

```
<UserControl ... x:Name="self">
    ...
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MessageList, ElementName=self}" />
    ...
</UserControl>
```

---

Besides that you should usually not set the DataContext of the UserControl to itself (like `DataContext = this;`) because that would effectively prevent inheriting the DataContext from the UserControl's parent element, which is necessary for an "external" binding to work, like:

```
<uc:RecentList MessageList="{Binding Messages}" />
```

Comment: This works perfectly, but, I'm still confused as to why (sorry). Does this answer imply that it was simply looking up the tree to the top layer, where as the RelativeSource tells it look only so far up the tree (if we assume the DataContext looks like XML tree)

Comment: RelativeSource just finds the first occurence of the specified type up in the element tree.

Comment: And without the ReleativeSource it was looking at the MainWindowViewModel! This is starting to make sense (already gave +1, will mark as answer in a few mins)