# Get property value WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying get a value from a property but isn't working I always get a null value.

```
string imageNormal;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageNormalProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ImageNormal", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow));

public string ImageNormal
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ImageNormalProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageNormalProperty, value); }
    }

public ButtonImageStyle()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        Console.WriteLine("Path: " + ImageNormal);
    }
```

Xaml ButtonImageStyle.xaml:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageNormal}" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

Xaml MainWindow.xaml:

```
<local:ButtonImageStyle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="88" ImageNormal="C:/Users/Xafi/Desktop/add.png"/>
```

I always obtain next output: 
Path:

Comment: Are you binding anything to this property?  Where do you set it?  why is there an orphaned `string imageNormal` floating at the top?

Comment: @axlj Yes, I am binding

Comment: Got it -- thanks, so where do you assign the ImageNormal path?  Based on the code above, the property is never assigned?

Comment: You're hardcoding the DataContext when you write `DataContext = this`, so no value can be pass into the UserControl. Remove that line, and it will probably work as you expect.

Comment: I am doing a custom button and I want to save two states, then I am testing how to save a string property
@Rachel I deleted and still not work
axlj I am assing property from the designer

Comment: @Xafi where and when do you assign your property? Is the ButtonImageStyle class a DataContext of your image?

Comment: @Ilan Yes, I think, I have a MainWindow.xaml and a UserControl called ButtonImageStyle.xaml and I use that UserControl in MainWindow.xaml writing default property at it

Comment: If I do 
            Console.WriteLine("->" + Button1.ImageNormal); from MainWindow it work

Comment: DataBindings resolve at runtime, not at design time. If you want to supply some data for use at design time, you can use the design prefix (typically defined as `d` in your MainWindow or UserControl, like `xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"` and `d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"`. In your case, it would be `d:ImageNormal="whateverValue"` to set the design-time value.

Answer (score 0):

since your ImageSource is  have to be binded to it's parent DependencyProperty (which is defined to your code behind), you have to define your binding to be rlative to your UserControl (let's name it *This*). Thus please try to change your xaml in the next way:

**Xaml code**

```
<UserControl x:Class="SomeBindingExampleSOHelpAttempt.ButtonImageStyle"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" x:Name="This">
<Grid>
    <Image Source="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=ImageNormal, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
           Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid></UserControl>
```

[Here you can find an additional perfect answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35179980/how-to-bind-liststring-to-a-dependencyproperty/35180470#35180470)

Regards.

Comment: But my objective is get the property values from code, and the values, introduce it from the designer i.gyazo.com/6ab8172860b0544cc5d81a89a3f0d9c6.png